# Why do for traditional loops perform differently than increasing a variable within a loop in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been working in Dart for a little bit and tried to make a function that returned a list of cards. I wanted each card to change colors when it was tapped and I have a listener to make sure that happens. I tried streamlining the program as much as possible to make the program easier to read. In this case, when I iterate over a loop and use `i` as a counter by increasing it at the end of every loop, the program does something I don't want, using the current value of `i` instead of its value when it is called. I was able to fix the problem by using a different loop type, but I have no idea why this changes anything.

Here is the original streamlined function:

```
List<Widget> nineCards() {
  List<int> numList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  List<Widget> output = [];
  int value = 42;
  int i = 0;
  for (int ele in numList) {
    output.add(
      Card(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            value = i;
            print('tapped! $value');
          },
          child: Container(
            color: value == i ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
            child: Text('element: $ele'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    i++;
  }
  return output;
}
```

Here is the fixed version:

```
List<Widget> nineCardsFixed() {
  List<int> numList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  List<Widget> output = [];
  int value = 42;
  for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
    output.add(
      Card(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            value = i;
            print('tapped! $value');
          },
          child: Container(
            color: value == i ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
            child: Text('element: ${numList.elementAt(i)}'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  return output;
}
```

And this is how I wanted to use the function:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: nineCardsFixed(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, I want to know why ```nineCards()``` uses the current value of ```i``` inside of the OnTap function instead of the initial value.

Comment: see https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @pskink shared earlier, the following link answers my question: dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops
"Closures inside of Dart’s for loops capture the value of the index" as opposed to the index itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StatefulWidget` to handle the changes in IU

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<int> numList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  int value = 42;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: nineCardsFixed(),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> nineCardsFixed() {
    List<Widget> output = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
      output.add(
        Card(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                value = i;
              });
              print('tapped! $value');
            },
            child: Container(
              color: value == i ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
              child: Text('element: ${numList.elementAt(i)}'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: I already found a way to update the UI, I want to know why ```nineCards()``` uses the current value of ```i``` inside of the OnTap function instead of the initial value.

Comment: You are declaring `i` value in common, so `i` value will be common for all the function `onTap`. Whereas for loop make variable `i` accessible for each item individually.